# pdftoprinter.exe Orientation page command

Tags: vb6

I need page orientation to landscape with a command through pdftoprinter.exe, does anyone know what parameter?

```
Dim retval
retval = Shell(App.Path & "\PDFtoPrinter.EXE C:\_GR\VB6\TEstePDF_Printer\pdfs\teste*.pdf ", 0)
```

Comment: Are you referring to http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html or some other tool?

Comment: This doesn't look like a Code issue. It looks like a command line tool that you are trying to find the correct switches for.

Comment: yes and this one http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation on that page that suggests there is such an option. Maybe you can contact the author and ask them? Their email address is at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the orientation, you can use the advise given on the documentation of using the dat-file created by PDF-Xchange viewer:

*By default, this system uses these printing options as set in PDF-XChange Viewer: Scaling is set to None; Auto-rotate Sheets; Auto-centre pages in sheets; and Choose paper source by PDF-page size. If you want to change any of these, or choose any other options, download and install PDF-XChange Viewer; open a PDF file, go to the Print menu, set your desired options (and, just to be certain, print the file). Then go to the Edit menu and choose Export All Settings to Data File... Accept the suggested filename, "PDF-XChange Viewer Settings.dat", and save the file to a convenient location. Move or copy the file to the same folder with PDFtoPrinter.exe. When you next run PDFtoPrinter.exe it will use the settings saved in that file.*

Found [here](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20this,in%20that%20file.).

Mind that:
*Move or copy the file to the same folder with PDFtoPrinter.exe.*

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work. what's weird is i'm printing a landscape doc pdf (prints normally in chrome) and pdftoprinter is rotating the content before print

Comment: Did you made a physical print in the PDF-XChange viewer before saving/exporting the settings?

Comment: Yeah I did... I had to move pdf_to_print and the settings file to same folder as python module that calls it, which is not ideal for me... Now it seems to work fine sometimes, or other times it opens pdf_viewer with no files opened, when I close viewer the file prints silently as desired... I'm relatively happy... Its there away to allow placing pdf_to_print in another folder? I want it in dist with a load of other bins...